# Recommend graphics card for setup

Tags: graphics-cards, pc

Setup:

- INTEL Core i5-3450 3.10GHz 1155
- ASROCK B75 Pro3
- (**2 x 8GB**) KINGSTON 16384MB HyperX Blu DDR3 1600Mhz CL10 KIT KHX16C10B1K2/16X
- Dell E2414HM LED Monitor, 24"
- THERMALTAKE TR2 RX W0146RE 450W

I have 350$ budget, but this is only an upper limit.

I was thinking about Nvidia 1060, 6GB.

I'll use it for casual gaming, would like to run the new games on high res for 1-2 years.

Comment: First of all, what is the wattage rating of your PSU?

Comment: If you could increase your budget to $370, you could afford the beefier/more powerful GTX 1070. Would that be an option?

Comment: Well it could be. Is this 41% a valid data?  http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1070-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1060-6GB/3609vs3639

Comment: It depends... It might be better to look at benchmarks that compare the GTX 1070 and GTX 1060 benchmarked using the games you want to play.

Comment: What I meant is the site I linked is something I can rely on?

Comment: I'm not sure about userbenchmark, I usually use Passmark for CPUs and GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your budget of $350, some sort of a non-reference Nvidia GTX 1060 is going to be a pretty good option.

I personally have a GTX 1060 that I occasionally game on. However, I primarily use it for CUDA. I am quite satisfied with its performance for how much I paid.

---

**The GTX 1060 meets your requirements:**

- Under budget of $350
- Can play modern games with good quality

**In Addition:**

- Your PSU meets the recommended PSU wattage. However, you will need a molex to 8 pin PCIe power or a 6 pin PCIe to 8 pin PCIe adapter.
- It supports CUDA, if ever you need to use GPU assisted rendering.

---

In conclusion:

I would recommend a GTX 1060, such as this Twin Frozr VI from MSI, which you can get for [$260 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IEKYD5U) or for [$275 on Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127963).

Comment: Just a note, I believe the PSU they have can actually run that GPU since it has a 6+2 Pin PCIe connector (6+2P is safely the same as an 8P), so there would be no need for a 6P to 8P adapter.

Comment: @MrPublic Thanks for pointing that out, you are correct. I guess I didn't see the "+2" part. I'll edit the question.

Comment: However I do not have the 6+2 cabe, I may have lost it or they didn't even provided it at all. Anyways, do I need to take anything to consideration when i buy a 6 to 8 pin adapter? I suppose I have to connect it to the red slot on the PSU.

Comment: Well the specs page says the 8 pin pci-e is a removable component (since it has a connection on both side according to the figure). But I'm not sure if I interpret it correctly :O. http://www.thermaltake.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00001558

Comment: @FerencDajka I looked at thermaltake's site for your psu and didn't see anything about the pcie power being removable. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I made a screenshot from the page I linked before, I marked the 8 pin connector, it has connection on both ends. http://imgur.com/a/22JVw

Comment: @FerencDajka Oh I see now.